# angularjs single page application URL error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi guys I created small SPA in angularjs. I have 3 links in navbar. When I click to the links instead of loading different pages in upload everytime the same page. Below is my routeProvder code:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('confusionApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

        // route for the menu page
            .when('/menu', {
                templateUrl : 'menu.html',
                controller  : 'MenuController'   
        })

        // route for the contactus page
            .when('/contactus', {
                templateUrl : 'contactus.html',
                controller  : 'ContactController'
            })

        // route for the dish details page
            .when('/menu/:id', {
                templateUrl : 'dishdetail.html',
                controller  : 'DishDetailController'
            })
            .otherwise('/contactus');

});
```

And html navbar code:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/home">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/menu">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                         Menu</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#/contactus">
                     <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

What I realised from error each time instead of changing URL over the # as in below:

```
http://127.0.0.1:55846/app/index.html#!/menu
```

It tries to access different URL over the contact us:

```
http://127.0.0.1:55846/app/index.html#!/contactus#%2Fmenu
```

So simply it access to otherwise part of route provider and tried to reach url over that and because there is no URL like that, it redirected to contactus page. I would like to know why it doesn't access to route for "menu"? 
P.S. when I type first URL manual it works.

Comment: Is this angular 1 or 2?

Comment: This is angular 2

Comment: Which file is your routes in?

Comment: menu.html, contactus.html and dishdetail.html. The problem is that whatever I write in there in redirected contactus. But manullay when I write URL it works. It calls all files which I need

Comment: I am sorry, I mean the actual routes your showing above. In the angualr2 quick start I believe the routes are in app.module.ts. I put mine in app.routes.ts I want to see the whole file your routes are living in.

Comment: Sure. I shared all code in github could you please go the link in below: https://github.com/Agyolchu/restaurant-theme.git

Comment: Here is all structure and code: https://github.com/Agyolchu/restaurant-theme.git

Comment: Ya bro that is angular 1. I am pretty sure. You are using scope which they took out of angualr2. Also in Angular 2 we use typescript and it compiles to js. Did you mean to use angular2? You might be following a tutorial and then using angular2 docs which could be confusing you?

Comment: Yeap Wuno. I think you are right and probably the reason is I installed "angular-route" for angular2 and trying to use component from the angular 2 . But I use angular 1 from course. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok no problem! I answered the question below regarding your problem. If I helped you and helped solve your issue please accept it. ALSO Let me know if you want some suggestions on angualr2. If you are set on wanting to learn angular and you have a course than great. But angular2 is much different and I suggest you learn it if you are just now starting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136008/discussion-between-agil-yolchuyev-and-wuno).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem here is that you are taking a course or following a tutorial for angular 1 but then you are trying to read docs which use angular2. I noticed you're using `$scope` in your github link which you shared and `$scope` was removed in the release of angular2.

I think to solve this you need set back to the last time your project worked and removing everything to that point. Then make sure when you add to your project from there you are using angular 1 features.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded your code and checked the dependencies in the index.html code, in the line where you call the controller, you have a typo:

```
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="scripts/controller.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much @Steven. This was my fault I didn't create name correctly in github. But that's correct in my computer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As was sayed before this was verion issue. I am writing this maybe someone will face the same problem in the future. So the reason was simple. When you will install angular route ( bower install angular-route -S ) it will suggest you two different version for installing. You must choose first because the the part was created base on Angular version 1. The second version of angular-route will try to render template as angular 2 component. So you must install version 1.4.14 for normal rendering template. After that when you will click to menu item it will open link http://127.0.0.1:57035/app/index.html#/menu . Otherwise it will try to render everything over the contactus because it cannot find menu item.

Answer (score -1):

Try calling to:
http://127.0.0.1:55846/app/index.html/#/menu

More information on w3school.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work: it works only when I use link as in below:http://127.0.0.1:57035/app/index.html#!/menu